# Not getting value from another sql table

Tags: php, sql

Hi I have two tables to consider while displaying data
`Table:product_desc` has `product_id` and `product_name`
the table I am reading from is `user_table` and I read `product_id` from there

code where I display data:

```
  $db = $registry->get('db');

$query = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user_table";
$data = $db->query($query);
//update
if ( $data->num_rows ) { ?>
<div class="">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SNo.</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Product ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $count = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach($data->rows as $k => $v){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $count++ ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v['product_id']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

I am trying to achieve something where I can display product_name from table `product_desc` for matching product_id of table user_table
Query like: `SELECT` product_name from `product_desc` where `product_id = " .$product_id";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use sql join like this:

```
$db = $registry->get('db');

$query = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user_table LEFT OUTER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_desc ON " . DB_PREFIX . "user_table.product_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "product_desc.product_id"  ;
$data = $db->query($query);
//update
if ( $data->num_rows ) { ?>
<div class="">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SNo.</th>
                <th>User Name</th>
                <th>Product ID</th>
                <th>Product Name
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $count = 1; ?>
        <?php foreach($data->rows as $k => $v){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $count++ ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v['username']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v['product_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $v['product_name']; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: this is not working where are you storing value for $product_name

Comment: You right, i updated my answer. Please try again. @raulxbox

Comment: here you are joining two product_id but I want product_name assigned to that product_id

Comment: user_table has every thing I need but it also has prodcut_id... product_desc also have same product_id and I just want product_name from that table so that I can display it here

Comment: in your query how are you getting product_name?

Comment: You can limit columns that received by using something like this:
`"SELECT " . DB_PREFIX . "user_table.*, " . DB_PREFIX . "product_desc.product_name FROM "`...
This cause you get all columns of user_table and only product_name column from product_desc

Comment: I am still not getting it this is my query can you please edit this:
$query = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user_activities, " . DB_PREFIX . "product_descriptions LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_descriptions ON " . DB_PREFIX . "user_activities.product_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "product_descriptions.product_id"  ; I just need product_name from this other table

Comment: Try this: `$query = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "user_activities LEFT OUTER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_descriptions ON " . DB_PREFIX . "user_activities.product_id = " . DB_PREFIX . "product_descriptions.product_id"; `

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly you have two tables:
user_table - stores username and product_id?
product_desc which stores the product_id and product_name?

If this is the case and then you can join the two tables to produce a single result set with all the information you are trying to retrieve, something along these lines should work:

```
"SELECT username, product_name FROM user_table OUTER JOIN product_desc WHERE user_table.product_id = product_desc.product_id";
```

Of course from the code snippet you have provided above you will want to add further columns name to the select to get all the data you wish to display.

Try looking at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html to learn more about joining tables

Comment: how do I use the value from product_desc and use product_name

Comment: @raulbox Not sure what you mean by that I'm afraid?